# free cmd/powershell replacement with normal copy paste

Tags: command-line, powershell, paste

I don't know why, but I hate pressing ctrl+v and getting `^V` in the powershell and cmd windows.

I always do it and then I have to back space it, out find my mouse, then right click, and select paste.   Grrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Is there a (free) fix to this?  Some way to say, hey, I want ctrl+V to work like the other 99.999999% of the applications out there!

Comment: I'm sure that can be done with AHK ...

Comment: @Johannes - What is AHK?

Comment: [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: The way I paste into a command window is to press Alt+Space E P.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy with Autohotkey:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^v::
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
return
```

Save that with an "ahk" extension and run it.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a AHK for that. So thanks for doing that for me

Answer (score 5):

You can turn on Quick Edit mode in CMD and Powershell, this makes right mouse click into a paste (no menu fly out).

1. Right click on the top of your shell window (either CMD or powershell)
2. select Properties
3. check the box for Quick Edit.

Re do the steps but select Defaults in step 2, to make sure you will have the setting permanently.

Comment: Still needs a mouse. Which isn't very natural when working in the console. It's a non-issue on a laptop with a nipple mouse, but everywhere else it's a nuisance.

Comment: Yes, good point.  Check out this for setting it up with AutoHotKey: http://lifehacker.com/5613776/enable-ctrl%252Bv-paste-in-the-windows-command-prompt-with-autohotkey?skyline=true&s=i

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

1. [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
2. [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)
3. [TCCLE](http://jpsoft.com/index.html) the free version

Comment: Console2 nor Powershell have ctrl+v paste options (that I could find).  If you know a way, please post it.

Comment: @Vaccano Console2 supports `ctl+insert`, `shift+insert` as copy and paste commands. They could be 'translated' to `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+v` using some [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell ISE. It uses the usual Windows Shortcuts

Comment: neither ctrl + C or ctrl + V work. What are you talking about?

Comment: PowerShell ISE is a grafical PowerShell host which comes as alternative to the console host. In some server installations it is not enabled by default. It is a true part of PowerShell since version 2. It is a windows application based on WPF and uses Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V for copy and paste. Take a look at this http://4sysops.com/archives/windows-powershell-ise-the-better-command-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but:

http://pscx.codeplex.com/

There's a command for getting clipboard:

http://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/73549#53777

You could perhaps add this to a Ctrl+V menu item and see if it works out.